# Installed Ubuntu (on its own partition, Windos 8 machine) and lost both boot options in BIOS

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I partitioned the unit in Windows first, and after I disabled Windows in BIOS because it wasn't allowing the boot CD to load. After the installation, the option to enable Windows and the option to enable Ubuntu in BIOS were no longer there. How do I get them to function?

[image: picture 1]
[image: picture 2]

Comment: In the future, it's probably better to just post Ubuntu-related questions here and use unix.stackexchange.com just for other distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For BIOS issues I'd recommend contacting the manufacturer of your motherboard/system/laptop. I'll narrow it down for you if you provide the make and model of your system in your question.

Based on your comment I believe you have an ASUS S46CA you can contact the manufacturer about repairing your BIOS boot options [here](http://www.service.asus.com/#!consumer/csn9)

Comment: @SurvMach updated answer with manufacturer contact info for your laptop. They will be able to help you. If this answer works for you please upvote/accept it. Thank you!